# Can't get a scroll view to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've been trying all day to get a very simple screen scroll working in Xcode 5 and just can't do it.

Even this simple tutorial doesn't work for me http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Knw41Tz_M.  All that does is add a scroll view to the view controller and when run, it shows a blank screen that can scroll - seen by the bars at the side.  No matter what I do, I can't get this to work.  First time I've needed scrolling and I am obviously missing something incredibly simple.

Simple .h code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
}
```

The .m code is

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
}
@end
```

The `Scroller` is connected to the scroll view, and that is about it!  I've tried adding in a `UIView` to the `UIScrollview`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: When you debugged this, what info about `Scroller` did you find?

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of "doesn't work"? What do you expect and what do you actually see?

Comment: What I was expecting to see was a blank screen that would scroll up and down as could be seen by scroll bars on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to move to `viewdidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`

Try changing your method to this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do that that, it brings up a 'no visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'viewdidAppear'.

Comment: That might be a hint on your problem, perhaps the class name is causing this, can you try renaming the class from `ViewController` to `myViewController` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is wired, I followed your code and something happened to reset scroll view content size as CGSizeZero if I add subview into UIScrollView in IB. If I add subview by code, the scroll view would be properly. I haven't figure out reason yet.

But one thing you can work around is that you can set scroll view content size in
 - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated.

Or add subview by code in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

i am not good at english, i just will show code what is work..

Simple .h code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
}
```

The .m code is

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(something) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)something {
    //[Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES]; !!!This don't need..
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
}

@end
```